# setting an array element with a sequence error (Programming computer vision in with python book)

Tags: computer-vision

I just follow the exercise from the book called Programming computer vision in with python. I'm trying to execute the following code but it give me errors.

```
from PIL import Image 
from numpy import * 
from pylab import * 
import imtools 
import pca

# Uses dense pca codepath.
imlist = imtools.get_imlist('D:\Programming computer vision with python\Basic image handling and processing\Data1')

im = array(Image.open(imlist[0]))  #open one image to get size 

m,n = im.shape[0:2] # get the size of the images 

imcount = len(imlist) # get the number of images

# create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], "f")

# perform PCA
V, S, immean = pca.pca(immatrix)

# show some images (mean and 7 first modes)
figure() 

gray() 

subplot(2, 4, 1) 

imshow(immean.reshape(m,n)) 

for i in range(7): 

    subplot(2, 4, i+2) 

    imshow(V[i].reshape(m,n))

show()
```

when i compile this code it gives me this error:

```
immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], "f") ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What should I do?

Comment: imlist = imtools.get_imlist(r'D:\Programming computer vision with python\Basic image handling and processing\Data1')

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried it but it doesn't work. Does the picture used in this program related to the problem or not ?